# Update MySQL column in one table based on the number of rows in another table

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL table labeled wp_posts that contains a comment_count column. It also contains an ID column.

I have another table called wp_comments with a column labeled comment_post_ID. The comment_post_ID column contains the ID associated with the post that the comment is located on. For example, if the post's ID is 10 and there is a comment located on that post, the comment_post_ID value for that comment will be 10. Multiple comments (wp_comments) will have the same comment_post_ID value.

In other words, if there are 10 wp_comments entries that all have the comment_post_ID value of 7, the value of the comment_count column will be 10 on the wp_posts entry that has the ID value of 7.

I need to up the comment_count column for each wp_posts entry based on how many entries in the wp_comments table share the same ID. The below code obviously won't work but maybe it will give a better picture of what I am needing:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_comments.comment_post_ID(count) = wp_posts.comment_count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update syntaxis is like this

```
UPDATE wp_posts P
JOIN wp_comments C 
  ON P.id = C.post_id
SET P.count = C.something
```

But to calculate the count you need use an aggregated query first

```
UPDATE wp_posts P
JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) as total_comments
      FROM wp_comments
      GROUP BY post_id ) as C
  ON P.id = C.post_id
SET P.count = C.total_comments
```

Additional Note: You probably don't want add this count column anyway, because you will have to update the field every time someone makes a comment. Maybe better create a view with the above query so you can get the count when need it.